# Delete an element's content from a file created with fopen

Tags: php, edit, fopen

I have a script that creates files with some data in it.
The contents are seperated by div with classes such as :

```
<div class="2017-02-01-20-35-company1">
//content
</div>
<div class="2017-02-01-20-35-company2">
//content
</div>
```

However, I want to be able to `edit/delete` each `div` from the created file, not just create the file or delete it entirely.
I can retrieve the name of the file and the name of div.

But is it possible to delete the div I want to delete as well as its content ?

thanks.

Comment: Keep the information you use to generate the file in a different format, either in the database or in a file, operate the changes on it and regenerate the HTML file after each change. It's easier and less error prone.

Comment: Read this maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: You certainly can use a DOM parser to work on such structure. But keeping it in a file means you have to re-read, re-parse and re-write it for every modification. It makes much more sense to keep the information in some storage location that is much better suited for such tasks, typically a database as @axiac mentions above, and only export the current state the moment you actually need it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the class of the div you want to remove it using a regex pattern to capture everything between the known div including its tag.

This is achieved through the use of **preg_replace()**

The method i would follow is:

```
<?php
//Set div class string to remove
$classString = "2017-02-01-20-35-company1";

//Get file contents
$contents = file_get_contents("/path/to/file.html");

//Remove div from contents
$search = '/[<div class="'.$classString.'">](.*)[<\/div>]/';
$contents = preg_replace($search, '', $contents);

//Save file again
file_put_contents("/path/to/file.html", $contents);
```